# Error: Module `@nuxtjs/firebase` not found

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I tried to install @nuxtjs/firebase, I followed all instruction here: https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/getting-started/

but I got error:

> Error: Module `@nuxtjs/firebase` not found.

[image]

Comment: Did you run `yarn add @nuxtjs/firebase`?

Comment: I did, I use npm to install.

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^6.0.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.0.0"
  },

Comment: I don't see any problem. maybe cleaning cache and reinstall node_modules helps.

Comment: it works now, I install with yarn

Comment: How did you solve it? i have removed node_modules, i run npm again but i get the problem when running any npm command run dev, start, build...

Comment: @JG_GJ, please install with Yarn.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the way it worked for me with yarn

Comment: yarn add @nuxtjs/firebase works

Answer (score 1):

Delete **npm_modules** folder and run `npm install` or `yarn install`

Answer (score 0):

If you project is already initialised with git, try `git clean -fdX`. It will delete your `node_modules` and `dist` or `build` folders. After than try installing again all your dependencies using `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

updated!

I don't understand why, but I tried to use

```
npm i @nuxtjs/firebase --save (Error: Module @nuxtjs/firebase not found.)
npm i firebase --save (firebase package not found)
```

I tried to delete node_modules, and reinstall with

```
yarn add @nuxtjs/firebase
yarn add firebase
```

and it works fine. 
hope it help someone later.

Comment: my nuxt stopped with Error: undefined after yarn add command